# How can I set a different subject and email reseiver for a powermail form?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, powermail

I am using TYPO3 6.2.15 and powermail 2.5.0 and want to set different subjects and receivers for a specific select field.

For this reason I have created a simple powermail form with a select field and the following options:

```
subject1 | 1
subject2 | 2
subject3 | 3
subject4 | 4
```

After that I have inserted a standard powermail form on a page and I have created a extended template for this page which contains the following typoscript:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|56 = 1]
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.subject = subject1
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.email = email1@email.de
[global]
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|56 = 2] OR [globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|56 = 3] OR [globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|56 = 4]
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.subject = subject2
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.email = email2@email.de
[global]
```

**56** is the id of the specific select field, but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now :). It didn't work because **56** is the id of my select field, but this is not the variable name in my case. The variable name is **subject**. So the following typoscript is working now:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|subject = 1]
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.subject = subject1
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.email = email1@email.de
[global]
```

(You can find the variable name if you inspect the element with the developer tools inside your browser or if you open the extended tab of your field within the backend of TYPO3)